# Unity3d bunny hopping controller. My velocity decreases when I'm strafing fast

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, controller, frame-rate

I created a FPS Movement script in unity3d for bunny hopping with references from [there](http://flafla2.github.io/2015/02/14/bunnyhop.html), but I have some issues.When I am strafing fast my speed decreases.
I wanted to create something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/embed/vvh3zRyviO8?start=27&end=39&version=3)

This is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour {

    //Strafe Variables
    public float gravity = 3f;
    public float ground_accelerate = 50f;
    public float max_velocity_ground = 4f;
    public float air_accelerate = 150f;
    public float max_velocity_air = 2f;
    public float friction = 8;
    bool onGround;
    public float jump_force = 5f;
    private Vector3 lastFrameVelocity = Vector3.zero;

    public Camera camObj;

    Rigidbody rb;
    Collider coll;

    void Start () {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
        coll = GetComponent<Collider> ();
    }


    void Update () {

        Vector2 input = new Vector2 (Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis ("Vertical"));

        Vector3    tempVelocity = CalculateFriction(rb.velocity);

        tempVelocity += CalculateMovement (input, tempVelocity);

        rb.velocity = tempVelocity;

        lastFrameVelocity = rb.velocity;

        rb.velocity += new Vector3(0f,-gravity,0f) * Time.deltaTime;

    }

    public Vector3 CalculateFriction(Vector3 currentVelocity)
    {
        onGround = Grounded();
        float speed = currentVelocity.magnitude;

        //Code from https://flafla2.github.io/2015/02/14/bunnyhop.html
        if (!onGround || Input.GetButton("Jump") || speed == 0f)
            return currentVelocity;

        float drop = speed * friction * Time.deltaTime;
        return currentVelocity * (Mathf.Max(speed - drop, 0f) / speed);
    }

    //Do movement input here
    public Vector3 CalculateMovement(Vector2 input, Vector3 velocity)
    {
        onGround = Grounded();

        //Different acceleration values for ground and air
        float curAccel = ground_accelerate;
        if (!onGround)
            curAccel = air_accelerate;

        //Ground speed
        float curMaxSpeed = max_velocity_ground;

        //Air speed
        if (!onGround)
            curMaxSpeed = max_velocity_air;


        //Get rotation input and make it a vector
        Vector3 camRotation = new Vector3(0f, camObj.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, 0f);
        Vector3 inputVelocity = Quaternion.Euler(camRotation) *
            new Vector3(input.x * air_accelerate, 0f, input.y * air_accelerate);

        //Ignore vertical component of rotated input
        Vector3 alignedInputVelocity = new Vector3(inputVelocity.x, 0f, inputVelocity.z) * Time.deltaTime; 

        //Get current velocity
        Vector3 currentVelocity = new Vector3(velocity.x, 0f, velocity.z);

        //How close the current speed to max velocity is (1 = not moving, 0 = at/over max speed)
        float max = Mathf.Max(0f, 1 - (currentVelocity.magnitude / curMaxSpeed));

        //How perpendicular the input to the current velocity is (0 = 90°)
        float velocityDot = Vector3.Dot(currentVelocity, alignedInputVelocity);

        //Scale the input to the max speed
        Vector3 modifiedVelocity = alignedInputVelocity*max;

        //The more perpendicular the input is, the more the input velocity will be applied
        Vector3 correctVelocity = Vector3.Lerp(alignedInputVelocity, modifiedVelocity, velocityDot);

        //Apply jump
        correctVelocity += GetJumpVelocity(velocity.y);

        //Return
        return correctVelocity;
    }

    private Vector3 GetJumpVelocity(float yVelocity)
    {
        Vector3 jumpVelocity = Vector3.zero;

        //Calculate jump
        if ( Input.GetButton("Jump") && yVelocity < jump_force && Grounded())
        {
            jumpVelocity = new Vector3(0f, jump_force - yVelocity, 0f);
        }

        return jumpVelocity;
    }


    bool Grounded(){
        return Physics.Raycast (transform.position, Vector3.down, coll.bounds.extents.y + 0.1f);
    }


}
```